# Illegal mix of collations in ejb

Tags: mysql, ejb

On MySQL 5.1 with a database collation of `latin1_general_ci`, I get this Exception when I `UPDATE`:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
Error Code: 1267
Call: UPDATE medicaltestdetails, TL_medicaltestdetails SET medicaltestdetails.Status = TL_medicaltestdetails.Status WHERE medicaltestdetails.TestDate = TL_medicaltestdetails.TestDate AND medicaltestdetails.TestSerial = TL_medicaltestdetails.TestSerial AND medicaltestdetails.ConsultantId = TL_medicaltestdetails.ConsultantId AND medicaltestdetails.TestTime = TL_medicaltestdetails.TestTime
Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=Medicaltestdetails sql="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TL_medicaltestdetails (Chg BIGINT, Remarks VARCHAR(255), Result VARCHAR(255), Status VARCHAR(255), TestDesc VARCHAR(255), TestType VARCHAR(255), TestDate DATE NOT NULL, TestSerial VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ConsultantId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TestTime INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (TestDate, TestSerial, ConsultantId, TestTime))")
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both `medicaltestdetails` and `TL_medicaltestdetails`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably had add '&characterEncoding=UTF-8' onto my JDBC connect string.
if

```
mysql> show variables like "collation_database";
    +--------------------+-----------------+
    | Variable_name      | Value           |
    +--------------------+-----------------+
    | collation_database | utf8_general_ci |
    +--------------------+-----------------+
```

it is not like that
and

```
mysql> show table status;
    +--------------+-----------------+
    | Name         | Collation       |
    +--------------+-----------------+
    | my_view      | NULL            |
    | my_table     | utf8_unicode_ci |
    ...
```

it is not like that

do:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and change the encoding for the field:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN my_column column_type CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [NOT NULL];
```

or change the encoding of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Ciao

Luca

Comment: Thank you. You are the first answer I have found that highlights that the columns in the table can have their own encoding (regardless of the default encoding of the table).